# Oberon character in Avalon

Tags: the-resistance-avalon

At the end of the game, when the evil characters discuss who Merlin is, can Oberon reveal himself and join in the discussion?

Edit: I'm asking this because in the games I've played, even though Oberon is an evil character, he doesn't know who the other evil characters are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note - it's **Oberon** rather than Morgana who does not open his eyes during the reveal phase at the start of the game.

The rules say:

> Without revealing any Character cards, the *Evil* players discuss and the player with the Assassin character card will name one *Good* player as Merlin

So no character cards should be revealed, however the player who is Oberon can join in the discussion.

It's not really explicit whether or not a Good player could claim to be Oberon at the end of the game to try and confuse the Assassin.

Comment: Could you elaborate on Morgana opening eyes during the reveal phase at the start of the game? The way I've played it (and this could have been wrong) is that Morgana doesn't open her eye any time during the revealing phase. She only sticks her thumb out for Percival to see.

Comment: @nullgraph Here is the line in the opening script `Minions of Mordred, not Oberon, - I repeat not oh ber ron, open your eyes and look around so that you know all agents of evil.` So Morgana should know who evil is and evil should know who she is.

Comment: Morgana is a minion of Mordred. Oberon isn't. But both are evil.

Comment: Re "So no character cards should be revealed", no cards need to be revealed, but there's no harm in the evil players revealing the cards. It's less confusing it they do.

Comment: I like revealing the evil characters at the end it makes for interesting discussion. But I've never thought of a good person coming out as Oberon at the end of the game that is great!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the game, when the evil characters discuss who Merlin is, can Oberon reveal himself and join in the discussion?

> YES Oberon may join the discussion. But you have to remember, NO ONE IS ALLOWED TO REVEAL THEIR CARDS (except of course for the Assassin so we'd know who has the last say). So even if I say I am Oberon so that I may join the discussion, no one can actually confirm who I am. For all they know, I could be Merlin who is pretending to be Oberon to get the target off of me. That's how fun this game is. It keeps you second-guessing.

Comment: If you're quoting something, reference it. Otherwise this is plagiarism and does nothing to assure the reliability of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe I'm playing incorrectly, but I always played that both Oberon and Morgana are evil. Morgana appears as Merlin, and Oberon knows who all the other evil people are but they don't know who he/she is.

So in the reveal phase :

1) All the evil team would open their eyes put their thumbs out and see each other EXCEPT OBERON (So this could possibly be the Assassin, Morgana, Mordred and any other minions).

2) The evil people would all put their thumbs up and Oberon would open their eyes and have a chance to see who their team is.

3) All the evil people INCLUDING OBERON would put their thumbs up EXCEPT MORDRED and Merlin would have his chance to see.

4) Then Percival would see Morgana and Merlin with their thumbs up not knowing which was which.

I was under the impression Oberon was evil, but the rest of the evil team didn't know who they were. This may not be the correct way but it has worked for us.

And as for revealing characters at the end of the game I guess it is technically wrong, but we've always had all the evil people reveal their characters at the end (including Oberon) then the evil team discusses who they think is Merlin, but the Assassin gets the final say. Usually knowing who Mordred was gives a lot of clues, because Merlin may not have accused them right away. We've found the discussion doesn't give evil too much of an advantage and is fun. So we always have reveal evil their characters, then the entire evil team discusses, and at the end the Assassin just has to say "I assassinate ______" to make their choice.

Comment: They both are evil and this does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: @JoeW I'm confused how doesn't it answer the question? I do say they are both evil. I clarify how I play with Oberon since it seems it is different than how other people do and I explain that the way I've always played is Oberon can join in the discussion (and I admit this may not be the technical rules but it has worked for me)

Comment: 1) You say you might be playing them wrong but you play them as evil when the rule book spells out the fact that they are all evil. 2) you are talking about rules for the start of the game when the question asks about rules for the end of the game. 3) You are making guesses at the end of the game and character cards are not revealed at the end but evil does discuss to decide who they think Merlin is and the Assassin makes the call. 4) What little you do talk about the end of the game you talk about how it works when you play rather then how it should work when played in general.